# Can't install the "refinerycms-memberships" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, refinerycms

What can i do if i know there is a github repository for the gem but in the terminal i couldn't install the gem via 'gem install' or 'bundle install' because it fails with the following error:

```
Could not find gem 'refinerycms-memberships (= 1.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I couldn't find it on rubygems.org either, so is there any other way of getting it installed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bundle install` then I assume you're installing using a Gemfile. In this case, you can [specify a git repo](http://gembundler.com/git.html):

```
gem refinerycms-memberships, :git => "git://path.to/git/repo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for this gem, I found this line in my Gemfile to work for me:

`gem 'refinerycms-memberships', '~> 2.0.0', :git => 'https://github.com/rbriank/refinerycms_membership.git'`

Depending when you see this post, you might need to modify the version or possible add the

`:branch => ....` option.